# finding automorphisms of binary hermitian forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, quadratic-forms, hermitian

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ be its ring of integers. Write $\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ for the set of hermitian 2 x 2 matrices with entries in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Now, we have the action of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathcal{O}_K)$ acts on the set $\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ by the formula $\sigma(f)=\sigma f \sigma^{*}$ for  $\sigma \in \mathbf{S L}(2, \mathcal{O}_K)$ and $f \in \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{O}_K)$. Let $f \in \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ be a Hermitian matrix and
$E(f, \mathcal{O}_K)=\{\sigma \in \mathbf{S L}(2, \mathcal{O}_K) : \sigma(f)=f\}$ be the group of automorphs of $f$. I am studying on some examples. By brute force, i can find $\quad E\left(\left(\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right), \mathbb{Z}[i]\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\pm\left(\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right), \pm\left(\begin{array}{cc}i & 0 \\ 0 & -i\end{array}\right) \\ \pm\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right), \pm\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & i \\ i & 0\end{array}\right)\end{array}\right\}.$ I read some facts from the book Groups Acting on Hyperbolic Space, Mennicke, Grunewald, Elstrodt:
If $f$ is an indefinite Hermitian form then the $E(f, R)$ are up to conjugacy discrete subgroups of $\mathbf{S L}(2,\mathbb{R})$ or the Borel subgroup of $\mathbf{S L}(2, \mathbb{C})$ according to $\Delta(f)$ being negative or zero.

My question: For indefinite  binary quadratic forms we can find all automorphisms by solving a Pell equation. Also, we know that automorphism group in PSL_2(\Bbb{Z}) should be cyclic. Is there any method for finding the automorphs of indefinite binary Hermitian forms with entries in $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K$ is a fixed imaginary quadratic field? do we know the group structure of automorphism groups of indefinite Hermitian forms?

I would be glad if anyone show me a method or a reference.

Comment: Are you taking $K$ an imaginary quadratic field, or a more general number field? If it's more general, what do you mean by complex conjugation - are you just fixing a complex embedding?

Comment: In fact i focus on the case that K is imaginary quadratic field.

Comment: One has the trick $(\sigma^{T})^{-1} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  \sigma   \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ^{-1}$ Using this you can write your equation $\sigma f \sigma^* =f$, or equivalently $\sigma f = f (\overline{\sigma}^{T})^{-1}$, as a conjugate-linear equation in $\sigma$. This equation defines a quaternion algebra and your group is the norm one elements of the quaternion algebra, so this gives it to you as the solutions of a quadratic equation in four variables.

Comment: Do we know the group structure of automorphism group of indefinite Hermitian forms? (number field is imaginary quadratic field)

Comment: @WillSawin By the way, do you mean that all elements of automorphism group has norm 1?

Comment: I think the norm in this case matches the determinant, which because we're in $SL_2$ is $1$. If you want to know its structure as an abstract group, using the embedding into $SL_2(\mathbb R) $ it can act on the upper half plane, and then the group is equal to the fundamental group of the quotient orbifold, which has a very particular structure. Probably one can determine the genus, cusps, and orbifold points using the arithmetic of the Hermitian form. This would give you generators and relations, but not immediately say what the generators are as matrices.